# How to keep word always in the same line in textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, line-breaks

So I have this 400px * 200px textarea containing words like "so-me-thing". This results into this:

```
| This is so-me text with syl-lab- |
| les. I want the word syl-lab-les |
| to be on the same line.          |
```

What I want is this:

```
| This is so-me text with          |
| syl-lab-les. I want the word     |
| syl-lab-les to be on the same    |
| line.                            |
```

And I got no idea how to achieve this. Hopefully somebody understands what I'm trying to explain. I need pure css solution, not javascript or else.

Comment: it's already working: https://jsfiddle.net/jwdyc1rh/4/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
word-break: keep-all;
```

if you want opposite then

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [word-break: break-word;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) property, and try.

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
textarea{
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```